# In c# app, how to connect foreign key of subtask table in SQL?

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to create a Task Management System using C# Web API & SQL Server.

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

- Users can send POST requests to create a Task (with optional sub-tasks).
- Users can send GET requests to retrieve a Task (displaying all sub-tasks in the response if they exist)

Here are some of my current files:

Task DTO:

```
public class TaskDto
{        
public int Id { get; set; }        
public string Name { get; set; }        
public string Description { get; set; }
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
public DateTime FinishDate { get; set; }
public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Task.cs:

```
public class Task
{
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
public DateTime FinishDate { get; set; }        
public string Status { get; set; }        
}
```

Subtask.cs:

```
public class SubTask
{
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Status { get; set; }        
}
```

With the above code, I'm currently, able to POST & GET a Task, but I am struggling to add the Sub-Task part.

Can someone please advise what I need to do in order to be able to meet this requirement?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: SubTasks table would have a TaskId column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your classes would link up like this...

```
public class Task
{        
 public int Id { get; set; }        
 public string Name { get; set; }        
 public string Description { get; set; }
 public virtual ICollection<SubTask> SubTask { get; set; }
}

public class SubTask
{        
 public int Id { get; set; }        
 public string Name { get; set; }        
 public string Description { get; set; }
 public int? TaskId { get; set; }
 public Task Task { get; set; }
}
```

You can see that `Task` has a collection of `SubTask` and `SubTask` has a reference back to `Task` with a `Task` property and a `TaskId`.

**Update**: Since you're not using EF code-first, as I initially thought.

Your DTO could just have a list of SubTask, something like this:

```
public class TaskDto
    {        
     public int Id { get; set; }        
     public string Name { get; set; }        
     public string Description { get; set; }
     public virtual List<SubTask> SubTask { get; set; }
    }
```

Then, you could do something like:

```
var tasks = (from t in _db.Tasks
                        join st in _db.Sub Tasks on st.Id equals t.SubTaskId
                        select new TaskDto
                        {
                            Id = t.Id,
                            Name = t.Name,
                            Description = t.Description,
                             SubTask = st
                        });
```

This is all hand written, but it'll be along these lines.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I was to use the same DTO to create a task (& optional subtasks), what would that DTO look like?

Comment: From the initial question, I thought you meant code-first, but are you using ADO.NET?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I'm not using ADO.NET. I've updated my question to hopefully make things clearer

Comment: OK, how are you querying SQL? There are so many ways to do this, you might be using a SQL view, where you can retrieve all the data in one place, or maybe you're having to query the two entities separately?

Comment: I'm using `ApplicationDbContext` & linq. Here's an example of what the queries look like in my controller: `bool value = _db.Tasks.Any(a => a.Name.ToLower().Trim() == name.ToLower().Trim());`

Answer (score 0):

Better approach would be to add property nullable `ParentTaskId`, which is nothing but the task id of the parent task. I’m considering that task and sub task have same properties.

Otherwise create a separate class for sub task and add nullable `parentTaskId` to it as foreign key.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I have updated my question with my latest attempt. I craeted a `Subtask` class, but I don't know what changes to make to my DTO, etc. so that the two classes are linked

Comment: Then I would recommend to read this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key